# Smart Capture / Jquery conflict

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, jquery, form, smart-capture

I have created a smart capture form in the MC which is working just fine. However, I have now am working on enhancing the form and I noticed that once I add the Jquery library to the page the submit button no longer works when I remove it, it works again.

I am using the manual smart capture since I am doing some overrides.

The form itself just uses standard bootstrap form elements with some css but nothing that I am thinking that would cause a conflict with Jquery.

Not sure if anyone has any idea what could cause the form to not submit when it does just fine without the

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

%%[[name="FormPost";type="POST"] 
VAR @de, @de_col, @de_statusCode, @de_statusMsg, @errorCode

SET @de = CreateObject("DataExtensionObject")
SetObjectProperty(@de, "CustomerKey", "xxxxx")

IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("guid")) THEN
    SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "firstname")
    SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("firstname"))
    AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF

SET @de_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@de, @de_statusMsg, @errorCode)

IF @de_statusCode != "OK" THEN
    SET @destatusCode = InvokeUpdate(@de, @de_statusMsg, @errorCode)
ELSEIF @de_statusCode != "OK" THEN
    RaiseError(@de_statusMsg, 0, @de_statusCode, @errorCode)
ENDIF

]%%

<!-- AMP Processing Placeholder DO NOT REMOVE -->
    <input type="hidden" name="__successPage" id="__successPage" value="http://google.com" /><input type="hidden" name="__errorPage" id="__errorPage" value="http://yahoo.com" /><input type="hidden" name="__contextName" id="__contextName" value="FormPost" /><input type="hidden" name="__executionContext" id="__executionContext" value="Post" />
</form>
```

Comment: Any errors in your browser console?

Comment: No, I had jquery migrate added and it initially threw errors but once removed it is fine and the functions work as expected just the submit is not working but as soon as I remove the jquery library script submit works again. Not sure what is causing it. I don't use any instances that would invoke a jquey function to not submit

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, I found out that there was a piece of JS that was adding an effect to the button causing the submit to halt.